# Why do i get KeyError: 'Patch' when using Spyder?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, spyder

When i run the code using Spyder, I get a `KeyError:'Patch'` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 523, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\zqh\Documents\Python Scripts\untitled1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 265, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.spines as mspines
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\spines.py", line 17, in <module>
    class Spine(mpatches.Patch):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\spines.py", line 39, in Spine
    @docstring.dedent_interpd
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\docstring.py", line 108, in dedent_interpd
    return interpd(dedent(func))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\docstring.py", line 39, in __call__
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__ and func.__doc__ % self.params
KeyError: 'Patch'
```

Here is my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep 18 16:37:52 2013

@author: zqh
"""
# Import everything from matplotlib (numpy is accessible via 'np' alias)
from pylab import *

# Create a new figure of size 8x6 points, using 100 dots per inch
figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=80)

# Create a new subplot from a grid of 1x1
subplot(111)

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

# Plot cosine using blue color with a continuous line of width 1 (pixels)
plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")

# Plot sine using green color with a continuous line of width 1 (pixels)
plot(X, S, color="green", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")

# Set x limits
xlim(-4.0,4.0)

# Set x ticks
xticks(np.linspace(-4,4,9,endpoint=True))

# Set y limits
ylim(-1.0,1.0)

# Set y ticks
yticks(np.linspace(-1,1,5,endpoint=True))

# Save figure using 72 dots per inch
# savefig("../figures/exercice_2.png",dpi=72)

# Show result on screen
show()
```

When I try running the same code in an iPython notbook, the code works fine. I don't know why I'm getting this error when using Spyder and how to solve it. What can I try?

Comment: I ran your code on my version of Spyder (2.2.1) with Matplotlib 1.3.0 and did not encounter this error. What versions are you running on?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Notice that there is a four spaces indentation in the first line of your code, i.e. in `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` that could be giving you trouble. However, I tried it using the latest Spyder version running under Anaconda/Linux and it works perfectly fine.